# What is the probability that I will be one of the two winners out of 3 candidates?

Tags: conditional-probability, monty-hall

I am one of the three candidates for an award given to 2 people. Am I right in thinking that My chances of winning an award is 2/3?
Because if so, the other two also has 2/3 chances of winning and that adds up to 2. That doesn't make sense to me.... please help!! :(

Also, this is a modified Monty Hall problem but if I know somebody on the committee to tell me who the other winner is other than myself, then my chances of winning will reduce from 2/3 to 1/2. Is this thinking correct? I am super confused about this Monty Hall problem and would appreciate any help from you guys.!

Comment: It adds up 2 because there are 2 winners.

Comment: To your second question, it depends. If the decision was made first, then you were told about another winner, then you still have a $\frac23$ chance of being a winner. But, if the first winner was just chosen, and the second hasn't been before you were told, then the chance is $\frac12$.

Comment: We can't say anything about how your probability changes when somebody on the committee leaks the information.  Maybe he always leaks information to the other winner; maybe he always leaks it to the loser.  Who knows?

Comment: The remaining probability depends on how you asked the committee member. If you asked him "Name a random winner that isn't me", then your chances stay 2/3, but if you just asked him "Name a random winner" and he names somebody other than you, then your chances sink to 1/2.

Comment: Alternately, if you have been told which one is best of those two, without comparing to you (and thus that competitor is guaranteed to win), you still have 2/3 probability of winning.

Comment: Being a canidate means we can't really speculate on your probability of winning. In general, they will pick the best two of the three. This is (probably) not a random draw. Unless all three (or two of the three) are very debatably just as deserving, you either have no chance of winning, or you are guarenteed to win. If Schrodinger was alive he would probably be annoyed with this response, but if you're not doing a draw, probabilities for random outcome are not applicable.